# Oracle - return multiple counts as one query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a couple of queries, detailed below. I'd like to be able to run one SQL query which returns both counts, is this possible?

1.

```
select nvl(count(rowid), 0) from tablename where OPP = 'FOO' and date = 'BAZ';
```

2.

```
select nvl(count(rowid), 0) from tablename where OPP = 'BAR' and date = 'BAZ';
```

I've only found MSSQL specific solutions in my searches so far.

Comment: No need for the nvl, count will never return null.

Comment: are you wanting to _run_ these through SQLPlus? Toad? as a Stored Proc?

Comment: Do you want the two counts in one row as columns? Or do you want two rows?

Comment: @Cos Callis I want to run this with Toad for testing, then with Perl DBI as part of a larger Perl script

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you need them in a single row:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(CASE OPP WHEN 'FOO' THEN 1 END),
    COUNT(CASE OPP WHEN 'BAR' THEN 1 END)
FROM tablename
WHERE OPP IN ('FOO', 'BAR') AND date = 'BAZ'
```

(The GROUP BY approach by Thilo is a better generic solution anyway.)

**Edit:** I've removed `NVL()`. I had forgotten why I never use it.

Answer (score 8):

If the condition really looks like that (same table, only one field different in the groups):

```
select opp, count(*) from tablename
where date = 'BAZ'
group by opp
having opp in ('FOO', 'BAR');
```

For arbitrary queries:

```
select 'A', count(*) from tableA
union all
select 'B', count(*) from tableB
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer since this is the correct approach

Answer (score 4):

You could use a with statement:

```
with
count1 as (
select ...
),
count2 as (
select ...
)
select tot1, tot2
from count1, count2
```

Comment: If I run this as is, except with a valid select clause, I get 'tot2' invalid identifier. This is Oracle 10G btw

Comment: That would be the names of your column aliases.

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy Thank you for the query : )