# How to find count of items in a table by 2 groups

Tags: sql, oracle, count, grouping

To keep it simple, I have a table with 3 columns:

1. Request Id (eg. REQ1, REQ2, and so on)
2. Status (possible values - In Planning, Work in Progress, In Review, Completed)
3. Due Type (possible values - Due Today, Due Tomorrow, This Week, Next Week, In 15 Days)

Now, all I want to find out is, how do I arrive at a result which will tell how many In Planning are Due Today, how many In Review are Due tomorrow and so on.

Tried using count with over and partition by, but it gives me the count of statuses and count of due types but not a combination of both maintaining the relation

Comment: Check out this [SO Oracle question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6356564/oracle-return-multiple-counts-as-one-query). It should help you

Answer (score 1):

Are you just looking for aggregation?

```
select due_type, status, count(*)
from t
group by due_type, status;
```

If so, this is a basic SQL query.  You should brush up on `group by` and other SQL fundamentals.